# Debug react native debug APK in browser?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I have a debug-APK which uses react native. Is it possible for me to debug that in the browser so that I am able to see which line of JS code is executing at any given time? I also have the source code if required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is a chrome extension for that

https://websitetoapk.com/docs/debugging-with-chrome.html